# React custom hook useState initialization value not update through outside props

Tags: react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I have a custom hook that has a locale state value by using `useState`, and I set the initial value from outside props, but when my props changes, my internal state value didn't get updated, in addition I am not quite understanding that, how many instance of custom hook in my component or application lifecycle where each time it's been triggered?

Here is the code example:

```
// custom hook
const useCustomHook = (initValue) => {
   const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(initValue);

   useEffect(() => {
      console.log('initValue :>> ', initValue, ', isFetching :>>', isFetching);
   }, [initValue, isFetching);
}
// component
const myComponent = (props) => {
   const [shouldTrigger, setShouldTrigger] = useState(false);

   useCustomHook(shouldTrigger);

   onButtonClick = () => {
     setShouldTrigger(true);
   }
}
```

Here are the console logs that I get,

```
// when my component mouts
'initValue :>> ', false, ', isFetching :>>', false
// when button clicked
'initValue :>> ', true, ', isFetching :>>', false
```

as you can see, as long as I set my `shouldTrigger` to true from the main component, my custom hook gets invoked, however, the local state value `isFetching` inside my custom hook value is still false, shouldn't it be true as it'll be assigned from outside props every time? and is my above two `useCustomHook` the same instance or different? If there are different instance being called, why the second instance not set initial value as "true"?

Here is the code link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yma5my?file=index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'm not sure but I think it's because if you use useState you can define this value only once.
2. `and is my above two useCustomHook the same instance or different` they will be different.

You can rewrite your code to

```
// custom hook
const useCustomHook = (initValue) => {
   const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(initValue);

   useEffect(() => {
      console.log('initValue :>> ', initValue, ', isFetching :>>', isFetching);
   }, [initValue, isFetching);
  return [isFetching, setIsFetching]
}
// component
const myComponent = (props) => {
   const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useCustomHook(false);

   onButtonClick = () => {
     setIsFetching(true);
   }
}
```

***UPDATE***

I just got an idea how to write in style that you wanted from start, but my first suggestion still better(as i think)

```
// custom hook
const useCustomHook = (value) => {
   const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(value);

   useEffect(() => {
     setIsFetching(value);
   }, [value]);

   useEffect(() => {
      console.log('value :>> ', value, ', isFetching :>>', isFetching);
   }, [initValue, isFetching);
}
// component
const myComponent = (props) => {
   const [shouldTrigger, setShouldTrigger] = useState(false);

   useCustomHook(shouldTrigger);

   onButtonClick = () => {
     setShouldTrigger(true);
   }
}
```

It cause additional calling of setState but implements updating of state based on input props;

Comment: Hi @boikov, thanks for your idea, I see people did `return [isFetching, setIsFetching]` before, but I was kinda confusing the way of using like this. As the customHook returns `setIsFetching`, then in my component when does the button click of `setIsFetching(true)`, was it actually calling the `setIsFetching` of my component instance or my customHook instance? And what'd be the benefit of putting the `set` statement in return of custom hook ?

Comment: 1) `As the customHook returns setIsFetching, then in my component when does the button click of setIsFetching(true), was it actually calling the setIsFetching of my component instance or my customHook instance?` If you write as wrote in my first sample, you'll use setIsFetching of customHook instance.

Comment: 2) If you return some setMethods you can manipulate with data of this hook and call it somewhere. For example you have a hook that calculate data based on request result. You can pass it by props to hook method or you can use it in useEffect hook, `this.request().then((res) => setHookValue(res));`